# C noncomplicated code sample doesn't work

Tags: c

I'm  a beginner in the C language and I wrote the following code sample.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {
    int count=0;
    while(true) {
        char card_name[3];
        puts("Enter the card name");
        scanf("%2s",card_name);
        int val=0;
        switch(card_name[0]) {
        case 'k':
             val=10;
             break;
        case 'q':
             val=10;
             break;
        case 'p':
             val=10;
             break;
        case 'a':
             val=11;
             break;
        case 'X':
             break;
        default:
                val=atoi(card_name);
                if (val<2 || val>10) {
                   continue;
                }
                break;
        }

        if ((val>2) && (val<7){
           count++;
        }              
        printf("The current count is: %i",count);
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

But it doesn't work. Anyone knows how to fix it? The error that the compiler found is that there is a missing `{` between the end of the `switch` and the `if` statement following it.

Comment: `if ((val>2) && (val<7)) {` <- Missing parenthesis

Comment: Oh when you say "it doesn't work", you mean "it doesn't compile".  And you don't post the compiler error message!  Great!  Nice question.

Comment: Voted to close. Dear poster, have you not read the error your compiler reported?

Comment: Note that condition that lead to the same behaviour can be put together (see case 'B' and 'C' in the example linked here http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cplusplus/cpp_switch_statement.htm)

Comment: @Dariusz Actually he mentions the error reported, and it is indeed a little bit misleading

Comment: By the way, you know this will and in stack/heap corruption, don't you?

Comment: Can you not count brackets when told by the compiler that you have bracket issue?

Answer (score 2):

```
if ((val>2) && (val<7) )
                      ^^^ close the bracket
```

Answer (score 1):

Line

```
if ((val>2) && (val<7){
```

should be

```
if ((val>2) && (val<7)) {
```